# How to escape wildcard * in Test-Path for registry?

Tags: powershell, escaping, registry, wildcard

I'm using `Test-Path` to check the existence of a registry value under `REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\` but the literal `*` seems to be recognized as a wildcard. Is there a way to escape it? I tried `\*` and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Use the backtick character as escape character in Powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a registry key with an asterisk to Test-Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506196/passing-a-registry-key-with-an-asterisk-to-test-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`-LiteralPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.2#-literalpath) parameter like below -

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\"
```

From Microsoft's documentation -

**-LiteralPath**

> Specifies a path to be tested. Unlike Path, the value of the
> LiteralPath parameter is used exactly as it is typed. No characters
> are interpreted as wildcard characters. If the path includes
> characters that could be interpreted by PowerShell as escape
> sequences, you must enclose the path in single quote so that they
> won't be interpreted.